# Custom field for image, not showing image!

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

In wordpress 3 you can create your own custom content types (without plugins) natively.

I have done this and created a new "add image" field.

However, I'm having trouble displaying this image in my page. In the loop I am doing:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner_image', true); ?>
```

But, this just returns '49' (which I assume is the ID of the post). I have tried setting it to false as well, which when using var_dump() reveals an array only with this number in it. Where is the image path?

Many thanks for your help.
Michael.

EDIT:

Here's a screenshot of the admin area and the image I need to output in the loop:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgKry.jpg

```
<?php

    query_posts(array( 

    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'work', 
    //'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'DESC'

    ));

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

    ?>

    <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'show_in_home_banner', true) == "yes" ) { ?>

    <li class="slide">

        <div class="slide-image">
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>">
                  <!-- this is the line outputting '49' and not the image. -->
            <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner_image', true); ?>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-content">
            <h3 class="slide-header"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID) ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sub_title', true); ?></a></h3>
            <p class="slide-title"><strong><?php echo the_title(); ?></strong></p>
        </div>

    </li>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: what do you feed in to the add image field?? I mean the value.

Comment: Well the fact that it returns something tells us that the code above is written correctly. What is the value in the custom field? Also are you using query_posts() or new WP_Query() before this at all? echo the $post->ID to make sure it's correct.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help. I am going to put my loop code in the post above. I'm using query_posts()

Comment: Hi, here's a screenshot of the admin interface and the image I need to output in the loop. http://i.imgur.com/hsllK.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a custom plugin.  Is that the case?

Anyway for the line:
    `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner_image', true); ?>`

Why aren't you using something like:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'banner_image', true); ?>"/>
```

Another way to debug is to echo the post ID to the screen and see if it is indeed 49.  Let us know what's going on.